# Sending WM_KEYUP message to a window gives an OverflowException

Tags: c#, winforms, pinvoke, windows-messages, overflowexception

I am trying to implement a program that sends the same messages to a window that would be sent if a certain key is continuously pressed.
This is part of the code (entire Form1.cs code is [here](http://pastebin.com/cHu5TuQN) ) for the application:

```
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint wMsg, UIntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHandle, IntPtr childAfter, string className, IntPtr windowTitle);

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // find notepad process
        System.Diagnostics.Process[] p = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
        // find child handle of notepad process
        // that is where we can send WM_KEYDOWN, WM_CHAR and WM_KEY up messages to write in the window
        IntPtr childHandle = FindWindowEx(p[0].MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero,"Edit", IntPtr.Zero);

        // WM_KEYDOWN message with parameters for 1st key
        SendMessage(childHandle, (uint)0x0100, (UIntPtr)0x00000041, (IntPtr)(0x001E0001));
        // WM_CHAR message with parameters for 1st key
        SendMessage(childHandle, (uint)0x0102, (UIntPtr)0x00000061, (IntPtr)(0x001E0001));

        // WM_KEYDOWN message with parameters for n-th key
        SendMessage(childHandle, (uint)0x0100, (UIntPtr)0x00000041, (IntPtr)(0x401E0001));
        // WM_CHAR message with parameters for n-th key
        SendMessage(childHandle, (uint)0x0102, (UIntPtr)0x00000061, (IntPtr)(0x401E0001));

        // WM_KEYUP message
        SendMessage(childHandle, (uint)0x0101, (UIntPtr)0x00000041, (IntPtr)(0xC01E0001));
    }
```

Upon reaching the WM_KEYUP SendMessage in the code the program crashes and gives the error:

[image]

How can i fix this error?
The 4 SendMessage calls before the WM_KEYUP one work ok and they send 2 letter 'a' to notepad.

Thanks for your replies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are compiling for x86. On x86 targets, `0xC01E0001` is not a valid `IntPtr` value (the maximum is `0x7FFFFFFF`).

2 options here :

- You do use the value `lParam` in the target application. In this case you have to use another value for the `IntPtr`, or use the type `UIntPtr` (but this type is not CLS-compliant).
- You do not use the value `lParam` in the target application. In this case just pass `IntPtr.Zero` as `lParam`.

Comment: I took the 1st option since i want to copy the continuous keypress as much as possible (i need to do delays next), so i replaced IntPtr lParam with UIntPtr lParam and now it works as expected sending the message with no error. Thank you! :)